# Multiple installed version of OpenCV

Tags: macos, opencv, build, shared-libraries

Looking under `/usr/local/lib/` I see multiple version of OpenCV installed.

In my case versions 4.2.0 and 3.4.1, I want to leave only one version 3.4.1.

`brew list | grep opencv` print nothing.

Is it ok just to remove 4.2.0 libs by mask from `/usr/local/lib/` and `/usr/local/include/opencv4` ?

**Update:**

After I deleted 4.2.0:

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
3.4.1
python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
3.4.1
```

As I remember correctly I also needed to delete opencv4 data under  `/usr/local/share` and under some cmake dir.

Comment: Is it possible to have more than 1 opencv installation? When you checked the version from terminal, what do you get?

Comment: How to check version from terminal?

Comment: ```pkg-config --modversion opencv``` should work but if you are using python-opencv ```$ python
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__``` should work.

Comment: After I deleted 4.2.0

pkg-config --modversion opencv
3.4.1
python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
3.4.1

Comment: I am wondering that what was the result before deleting?

Comment: I already deleted opencv4, so I can't reproduce.